# How to return a list of courses between 2 months in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that returns a list of courses running between 2 months?

I've written code something like this:

```
create procedure final_RTrainerqualification
    (@TrainerID char(10),
     @Coursecode char(4) OUTPUT,
     @qualcode nvarchar(30),
     @coursedate datetime output)

DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20160401',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20160601';

SELECT coursedate
FROM dbo.RTrainerqualification
WHERE coursedate >= @MinDate
  AND coursedate < @MaxDate;`
```

It should be returning the list of courses that run between these 2 dates mentioned but I am new to stored procedure so my question is how do I assign coursedates to the courses and make it return the list?

Edit- used T-SQL to recreate the code

```
 @Coursecount smallint
declare @Coursedatebeg datetime, @Coursedateend datetime, @CourseCode char(4),@TrainerID char(10);
select @Coursedatebeg = '2015-04-20'
select @Coursedateend = '2015-06-20';
while @Coursedatebeg <= @Coursedateend
begin   
    select @CourseCode = @Coursedateend;
    select @Coursecount = count(*) from RCourseInstance
        where CourseCode between 'R222' and 'R224';
    if @CourseCount <> 0
        begin
            Print 'Courses running between April and June 2015 ' ;
            select Coursedate,CourseCode  from RCourseInstance as t
            inner join Coursedate as d on t.Coursedate = d.Coursedate
            inner join CourseCode as c on c.CourseCode = t.CourseCode
            where CourseCode between 'R222' and 'R224';
        end
    else    
        print 'No courses are running between these dates ' ;
    set @Coursedatebeg = @Coursedatebeg + 2;
end
```

[It is returning the print statement but also declaring that invalid object name Coursedate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEkD3.png)
what have I done incorrectly here?

Comment: Is dbo.RTrainerqualification the only table involved? Are there columns in other tables you need data from? Instead of assigning data to output variables, you just include the data needed in your select statement within the stored procedure. Include the Min and Max dates as parameters (not variables).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the courses you want to assign to? If you mean your OUTPUT parameters then the SELECT will only assign the value from one row (the last) to the variable (unless you specify TOP 1 with an ORDER BY). To return the full list you need to just include all the columns you need in the SELECT.

Comment: I need to return the list of courses that runs in the next 2 months so date between say,2016-04-01 and 2016-06-01, the courses taught between these months should be returned. but it is displaying all the dates without any course information. I have declared coursecode but is it because it hasn't been assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use ISO date strings to avoid regional settings issues. You are only returning the coursedate in the SELECT. If you want further information such as the coursecode then add it into the SELECT. i.e.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2016-04-01',
@MaxDate DATE = '2016-06-01'

SELECT coursedate, coursecode, *
FROM dbo.RTrainerqualification
WHERE coursedate >= @MinDate
AND coursedate < @MaxDate;
```

The OUTPUT variables are not required - these are needed when you want to return a single value rather than a list.

This is fundamental SQL stuff so I would strongly recommend you do some reading on this. There is a simple stored procedure tutorial [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/) to start off with.

Comment: thank you strickt01, i did use the select statement (I've not written it above)but unfortunately it  still printed out the values outside the range of date specified. I also checked the data type and format of date but it still returned the list of dates outside. Might have to use a select  coursecode,  where ... date between ' ' and ' ', anyway thank you for the answer and link!

Comment: Re. the format of dates. When specifying the date in a string in SQL it is always best to use the ISO standard. i.e. 'yyyy-mm-dd'. That avoids any issues with regional settings. I have edited my answer to include this. Then assuming the data type of coursedate is date or datetime you should not get any issues. If you do get unexpected results can you post them?

Comment: hello again,I tried a different logic (T-SQL) but I am getting the error invalid object name?

Comment: I'm afraid your SQL query is all over the place. The object name error is because you are trying to join to CourseDate which is a column not a table. I presume courseCode is the same. You also do not appear to be filtering by date anywhere in your SELECT statement - only by CourseCode. The line `set @Coursedatebeg = @Coursedatebeg + 2` adds 2 days which again makes little sense in what you are trying to achieve. I could go on. Sorry to say you are going to really struggle unless you do some reading around basic SQL syntax and concepts.

Comment: I get your point. thanks for looking at it all the same, appreciate the f/b